# Titanium - How to keep popover from disappearing when taking picture from the camera?

Tags: ios, camera, titanium, image-gallery, popover

I'm working with Titanium Studio 2.1 and developing for iOS 5.1, we're working on an app that shows a popover for displaying a selected image, the image can be chosen when you press a button and a dialog is shown, in said dialog one can choose to pick an image from the gallery or to take a new one from the camera.

When choosing the image from the gallery, the usual popover gallery is shown and the image can be picked with no problem. However, when the camera option is chosen, the camera interface is shown, but the popover we opened to display the image is being shown on top of the camera interface. Then if we try to take the picture, the popover is hidden because we pressed outside of the boundaries of the popover.

I would like to make it so the popover doesn't appear in front of the camera interface and disappear when taking the picture.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: When the user selects the camera, are you closing the popover?  There should be something in your selection event listener to close to popover if it is still up.

Comment: the problem is that the popover has the default behaviour to hide when a click is made outside of its boundaries. I haven't found a way to dismiss this behaviour or better yet, open the camera in another popover so the previous popover doesn't close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to show the camera on a popover, that way it won't go full-screen and when clicked make the other popover to hide.

Here's the code:

```
Ti.Media.showCamera({
    inPopOver: true, // set this to true
    popoverView: btnCamera, // "view" for the pointer arrow direction
    success: function (event) {
        alert('success');
    },
    cancel: function () {
        alert('cancel');
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert('error');
    },
    saveToPhotoGallery: false,
    allowEditing: false,
    mediaTypes: [
        Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO
    ]
});
```

This is great since the camera on full-screen on the iPad looks bad.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting autohide: false in your call to showCamera? You need to showControls: false, autohide: false, and then call Ti.Media.takePicture() to take a picture.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/CameraOptionsType-property-autohide

Comment: i would recommend using the **latest** documentation [http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/CameraOptionsType-property-autohide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/CameraOptionsType-property-autohide)